# Unable to kill task via command line, "Access denied"

Tags: windows-10, command-line, tasks

Long story short, my dad has installed some parental protection software that I don't want running. It's easy enough to go to Task Manager and end task, but because the process starts up every time the computer is turned on, and I often forget to turn it off. 
I want to automate this by basically creating a .bat script that will kill the process(es) and assign it to Task Scheduler and make it run on start up, or make it run once a day or something.
But whenever I try to kill the task via Command Line or through a .bat file, I get the "Access Denied" error. E.g. `taskkill /IM <name.exe> /T /F` as well as `wmic process where "name='<name.exe>'" delete`. I'm an administrator on the computer and I've tried running Command Prompt as administrator, no change. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: if you redirect `tasklsit` to a log file before running the kill command, are you able to verify that the process exists at that time? Access is Denied/Error 5/0x80000005 errors are often not about access at all.

Comment: Are you sure you running the command line as admin?